# I want to make a UI as per diagram. I have to set JButtons in a JFrame, but I don't get the output as shown in the diagram. I tied. What should I do?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

[image: UI is here ....]

I tried like this...

```
class Calculator extends JFrame{
    // Here are the attributes
    Calculator(){
    // Here are the frame
    
    // here are the assign JPanels

    firstPanel.add(buttons[0]);
    secondPanel.add(buttons[1]);
        
    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++){
        thirdPanel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
        
    fourthPanel.add(buttons[6]);
    fifthPanel.add(buttons[7]);
            
    add(firstPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(secondPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(thirdPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(fourthPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(fifthPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);  `
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Try nesting a `GridLayout` in `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output as shown in the diagram you can try the following

```
 Calculator(){
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setTitle("this");
        //create first panel with BorderLayout as layout
        JPanel firstPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        //Create second Panel with GrdiLayout as layout
        JPanel secondPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        //add 4 Buttons to second Panel
        for(Integer i=0;i<4;i++){
            secondPanel.add(new JButton("Button"+i.toString()));
        }
        //Add wnorth,south,west,east buttons to first panel
        firstPanel.add(new JButton("north"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        firstPanel.add(new JButton("south"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        firstPanel.add(new JButton("west"),BorderLayout.WEST);
        firstPanel.add(new JButton("east"),BorderLayout.EAST);
        //add the second panel (containing 4 buttons) to first panel
        firstPanel.add(secondPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add first panel to the frame
        this.add(firstPanel);
        
    }
```

In main

```
public static void main (String args[]){

 new Calculator().setVisible(true);

}
```

Output:

[image]